# How to deal with unexpected props in TS React project?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

For example, I have a custom button component.

```
<button type={type} className={classes} {...props}>
  {!!children && <span>{children}</span>}
</button>
```

I passed other props that I don't want to predict with destructing. But TS will throw an error when I will try to pass, for example, **disabled** prop coz it not defined in the TS interface.

Is there some way to deal with this? Or the only way is to define all possible pros in an interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your specific case, your custom button props could extend HTML button props

```
interface MyButtonProps extends React.ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement> {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}

function MyButton({ children, ...props }: MyButtonProps) {
  return <button {...props}>{children}</props>
}
```

Comment: Cool, but can u give me a hit on how to extend this in functional components?

Comment: it is an interface. Use it to define the functional component's param type. See edited post